# How would a medieval society look if food was not a factor to consider?

Tags: magic, politics, food, natural-resources

## The Context

To give a short context of the question, my world is called Atmos, and it's a world where continents float above a layer of clouds. They aren't just floating islands, there are landmasses so large that some people in the world have never seen the edge of their continent (just as how there's people IRL who have never seen the sea in person).

The focus of the question lies in a place I called the Azarii Archiuranos (Archipelagos, but since "pelagos" stands for seas, I decided to call it Archiuranos (where uranos means skies) ), The creatures that live in this archiuranos feed off of Mana, basically a magical force, and these islands *reek* Mana, there's a gigantic, unstable node of mana in the center of the isles that projects a field of mana (It behaves similar to how radiation works, and the creatures that feed off of mana are loosely based on radiotrophic fungi).

The thing is, these creatures only feed off of mana to survive, which is widely available in the air, while they can decide to eat more as a method of both storage for when mana tides are low, or when they are outside of the Archiuranos, the presence of mana in the air means they never really starve while inside these isles, and therefore these species don't really need anything to survive.

Mana-Foods for these isles are something which is only considered for luxury and leisure more than sustenance, unless they are travelling outside of the Archiuranos, in which case they will need to supplement themselves with mana-charged foods.

Generally the creatures still age and die, and disease is something which can strike the isles, they are susceptible to every possible ailment, just not starvation. Chances are that diseases and other kinds of ailments would keep the population in check when it rises, and the dangerous magical beasts of the isles would still contribute to a bit of the population control.

## Internal Politics

How would the lack of need for food affect a society of creatures internally? I'm thinking that the times in which this world is settled in is based on medieval/renaissance times with a high fantasy flare and some Arcanopunk elements, but I'm not sure how would a society develop if the basic needs of sustenance are already basically granted. What would people do in such a society? There are different species within the isles as well, so variations might exist, I imagine, but what sort of common trends could one see?

In short: How would a society that doesn't have to worry about food structure itself? Would people from it focus their lives into craftsmanship, arts and sciences? Would any particular ways of government become more of a trend? Would Feudalism even be a thing still for such a society?

Comment: The problem with this sort of question is that you're making a fairly radical change, and then asking for a list of all the possible consequences. This list is more or less unbounded, which means there's no practical way for anyone to really answer. Each sub-part of your question is itself its own complex question. You need to focus on specific issues for which there's some definition of a correct answer, or at least a metric for "best" answer. Pick one aspect of your question, focus on that.

Comment: And whilst you're in edit-mode, have a think about what limits are placed on reproduction and population size. Does everything just keep breeding until stuff gets pushed off the edge of the islands? Do magic star bats eat half the population once a year? Does a rampant epidemic of turbopox keep the population down naturally?

Comment: There, got rid of the external politics part, I'll make it its own question later.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it fails "the book test": If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

Comment: I'm just asking for basic ideas on how a society would function if food was not a factor? How else would you want me to word a question in order for its answer to be specific enough while still providing any sort of meaningful answer? This is a worldbuilding site, I was hoping for at least some ideas or points to consider, not a whole written book. How would you word or separate a question like this in the first place, then? @Daron

Comment: Why would anybody think that a society where food is freely available would ever have a stage similar to western European middle ages? When you say that the society is "based on medieval/renaissance times" you need to have at least a broad and fuzzy understanding on what historical path of development put them in that situation; for example, the European medieval world was the result of the collapse of a previous globalized civilization. (And remember that the western European medieval society with its dual spiritual and secular hierarchy was a historically unique phenomenon.)

Comment: @Ghiojo The site is not about brainstorming. It is about solving focused problems. Start adding things to the world, until you encounter a problem. Then ask us about the problem.

Comment: During medieval times, more than ninety percent of humanity worked in raising food.  Removing this would change it so radically that it ceased to be medieval.

Comment: @Ghiojo This is a matter of reaching the perspective. For some the easiest is to take it from top to bottom : What domains see the most changes? Demography, wars, economy, industry, laws...? In one of the domain, what changed the most? And so on. You can also do the reverse, i.e. bottom-up approach : What would you do if you always had your fridge full? Take more care of your friends, have more fun...? What would you see in your town if your whole neighborhood do more or less the same thing you would do? And so on :).

Comment: Either way you'll reach a point you're either not sure or really have trouble putting puzzle pieces together : This will be the specific issue we can answer. Following the bottom-up approach, here's a sample, likely specific enough question I devised for instance : Without needing to look for food, festivals would become galore (since more free individual time); How can I make daily festivals work along with the maintenance of the city (building, street cleaning, healthcare...)?

Comment: This change would have a huge impact on human evolution. So much of our history is based on food insecurity - the violence, raiding, pressure to keep grandparents alive to help provide food for children, civilization itself, etc. Christopher Anvil had a story based on infinite food and wrote that the population pressures meant for short lives and no possible civilization.

Comment: Hello Ghiojo. It is important that you realize you've asked a frequently-asked but always-off-topic question. It's a [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/40609) of the form, "given condition X, what happens?" Questions like this violate a number of [help] rules including being too broad, open-ended, allowing all answers to have equal value, and not focusing on one, specific problem. We'd love to help you design your city, but it would help if you carefully read the [tour] and the following two Help Center pages: [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask].

Comment: One quick thought to get you moving: large animals (e.g. elephants) have limited intelligence because so much of their brain is used in controlling their complicated digestive system, and so much of their time is focused on eating. Take that away and you probably have a whole lot more intelligence develop in your whole animal kingdom.